# Flutter plugin callback called only for one instance but not for all instances

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I developed a Flutter plugin that was functioning properly until I integrated it into a single widget. However, I now have a requirement to use multiple instances of the plugin within that widget. The problem I'm facing is that the callback function is only being invoked for one instance and not for both instances.

Here is the code snippet for the plugin data:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class FlutterOnlineRadio {
  static const MethodChannel _channel = MethodChannel('flutter_online_radio');
  static int instance_count = 0;

  static int STATUS_IDLE = 0;
  static int STATUS_PLAYING = 1;
  static int STATUS_BUFFERING = 2;
  static int STATUS_PAUSED = 3;
  static int STATUS_ENDED = 4;

  int _playbackState = 1;
  bool _playWhenReady = true;
  int playerStatus = STATUS_IDLE;
  String playerStatusString = "";
  String instance = "";

  void Function(int, String, dynamic)? onStatusChange;

  FlutterOnlineRadio(String ins) {
    instance_count++;

    print("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
    print("Current instance : $instance , new : $ins, totsl instances : $instance_count");
    print("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
    instance = ins;
    _playbackState = 1; //STATE_IDLE;
    _playWhenReady = true;

    _channel.setMethodCallHandler((MethodCall call) async {
      print("New Method Call Received : -------------- $instance of $instance_count -------------- : ${call.method}" );

      if (call.method == "onPlayerStateChanged") {
        dynamic args = call.arguments;
        _playbackState = args["playbackState"];
        _playWhenReady = args["playWhenReady"];

        _setPlayingState();

        onStatusChange?.call(playerStatus, playerStatusString, args);
      }
      else if(call.method == "onTrackUpdate")
      {
        //print("FlutterOnlineRadio :: onTrackUpdate");

          //print("FlutterOnlineRadio :: onTrackUpdate :: _callBack");
        onStatusChange?.call(playerStatus, playerStatusString, call.arguments);

      }
    });

    _channel.invokeMethod('initialize');
  }

  // void onStatusChange(onClickAction) {
  //   _callBack = onClickAction;
  // }

  void playRadio({String url = '', String title = '', String imagePath =''}) async {
    await _channel.invokeMethod('play',
        {"url": url, "title": title, "imagePath": imagePath});
  }

  void playIfPaused() async {
    await _channel.invokeMethod('playIfPaused');
  }

  void playAlbum(
      {String data ='',
        String imagePath='',
        String baseUrl='',
        String dataDir='',
        int index=0}) async {
    //print("inside plugin playAlbum: index : $index");
    await _channel.invokeMethod('playAlbum', {
      "data": data,
      "imagePath": imagePath,
      "baseUrl": baseUrl,
      "dataDir": dataDir,
      "index": index,
    });
  }

  void stop() async {
    await _channel.invokeMethod('stop');
  }

  void pause() async {
    await _channel.invokeMethod('pause');
  }

  void seekTo(int milisecs) async {
    await _channel.invokeMethod('seekTo', {
      "milisecs" : milisecs
    });
  }

  Future<dynamic> getStatus() async {
    dynamic status = await _channel.invokeMethod('getStatus');

    _playbackState = status["playbackState"];
    _playWhenReady = status["playWhenReady"];
    //_title = status["title"];

    _setPlayingState();

    dynamic tmp = {
      "playerStatus": playerStatus,
      "playerStatusString": playerStatusString,
      // "title": _title
    };

    var returnVal = {};

    returnVal.addAll(tmp);
    returnVal.addAll(status);

    return returnVal;
  }

  void _setPlayingState() {
    /**
     * The player does not have any media to play.
     */
    const int STATE_IDLE = 1;
    /**
     * The player is not able to immediately play from its current position. This state typically
     * occurs when more data needs to be loaded.
     */
    const int STATE_BUFFERING = 2;
    /**
     * The player is able to immediately play from its current position. The player will be playing if
     * {@link #getPlayWhenReady()} is true, and paused otherwise.
     */
    const int STATE_READY = 3;
    /**
     * The player has finished playing the media.
     */
    const int STATE_ENDED = 4;

    switch (_playbackState) {
      case STATE_IDLE:
        playerStatus = STATUS_IDLE;
        playerStatusString = "";
        break;
      case STATE_READY:
        playerStatus = (_playWhenReady) ? STATUS_PLAYING : STATUS_PAUSED;
        playerStatusString = (_playWhenReady) ? "Playing..." : "Paused";
        break;
      case STATE_BUFFERING:
        playerStatus = STATUS_BUFFERING;
        playerStatusString = "Buffering...";
        break;
      case STATE_ENDED:
        playerStatus = STATUS_ENDED;
        playerStatusString = "";
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Following is the code for my widget:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter_online_radio/flutter_online_radio.dart';


class MyPersistentAudio extends StatefulWidget {
  MyPersistentAudio();

  @override
  _MyPersistentAudioState createState() => _MyPersistentAudioState();
}

class _MyPersistentAudioState extends State<MyPersistentAudio> {
  FlutterOnlineRadio flutterOnlineRadio =
      new FlutterOnlineRadio("persistent instance 1");
  FlutterOnlineRadio flutterOnlineRadio2 =
  new FlutterOnlineRadio("persistent instance 2");

  int playerStatus = FlutterOnlineRadio.STATUS_IDLE;
  String playerStatusString = "";
  String playingTitle = "";
  String imagePath = "";
  bool widgetActive = false;

  @override
  void initState() {

    flutterOnlineRadio.onStatusChange = (status, statusString, args) {
      kksPrint("my_persistent_audio.dart : onStatusChange");
      kksPrint(status);
      kksPrint(args);

      setState(() {
        //Just Refresh : Important
      });
    };



    flutterOnlineRadio2.onStatusChange = (status, statusString, args) {
      kksPrint("my_persistent_audio.dart : 2 : onStatusChange");
      kksPrint(status);
      kksPrint(args);
    };
    
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(playerStatus);

    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
      height: 50
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        child: Text("Radio ..."
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In the logs I can see only instace2 receiving callbacks but not 1

```
I/flutter ( 4848): New Method Call Received : -------------- persistent instance 2 of 2 -------------- : onTrackUpdate
I/flutter ( 4848): my_persistent_audio.dart : 2 : onStatusChange
I/flutter ( 4848): 0
I/flutter ( 4848): {duration: 3476940, audioId: audio_39_1, bufferedPosition: 2022008, albumId: audio_39, position: 2006515}
I/flutter ( 4848): 0
I/flutter ( 4848): New Method Call Received : -------------- persistent instance 2 of 2 -------------- : onTrackUpdate
I/flutter ( 4848): my_persistent_audio.dart : 2 : onStatusChange
I/flutter ( 4848): 0
I/flutter ( 4848): {duration: 3476940, audioId: audio_39_1, bufferedPosition: 2153090, albumId: audio_39, position: 2007498}
I/flutter ( 4848): 0
I/flutter ( 4848): New Method Call Received : -------------- persistent instance 2 of 2 -------------- : onTrackUpdate
I/flutter ( 4848): my_persistent_audio.dart : 2 : onStatusChange
I/flutter ( 4848): 0
I/flutter ( 4848): {duration: 3476940, audioId: audio_39_1, bufferedPosition: 2153090, albumId: audio_39, position: 2008514}
I/flutter ( 4848): 0
I/flutter ( 4848): New Method Call Received : -------------- persistent instance 2 of 2 -------------- : onTrackUpdate
I/flutter ( 4848): my_persistent_audio.dart : 2 : onStatusChange
I/flutter ( 4848): 0
I/flutter ( 4848): {duration: 3476940, audioId: audio_39_1, bufferedPosition: 2153090, albumId: audio_39, position: 2009522}
I/flutter ( 4848): 0
I/flutter ( 4848): New Method Call Received : -------------- persistent instance 2 of 2 -------------- : onTrackUpdate
I/flutter ( 4848): my_persistent_audio.dart : 2 : onStatusChange
I/flutter ( 4848): 0
I/flutter ( 4848): {duration: 3476940, audioId: audio_39_1, bufferedPosition: 2153090, albumId: audio_39, position: 2010503}
I/flutter ( 4848): 0
I/flutter ( 4848): New Method Call Received : -------------- persistent instance 2 of 2 -------------- : onTrackUpdate
I/flutter ( 4848): my_persistent_audio.dart : 2 : onStatusChange
```

Why am I only receiving callbacks for the second instance of FlutterOnlineRadio and not for the first? What modification should I make to receive callbacks for both instances of FlutterOnlineRadio?